# How does one convert a binary blob to source and why don't people do it?

Tags: android, c++, android-source

Richard Stallman says that a risk to users using Android, is that the source code for the binary blobs is unavailable, and it is unclear whether these blobs could have a hidden back door or undesired behaviour from the users perspective.

But since the blobs for Nexus / Pixel devices can be downloaded freely from the android website, what is to stop people from converting the binary to C++ source, and examining it ? The files aren't very large...

EDIT: Since the files aren't very large, if a number of people work on it, why would it be hard to examine every instruction ? I can understand that when the binary is converted to C++ source, each line of code would have to be examined, but my question is, since the files aren't too large there shouldn't be too many lines...

Comment: And what if the blob *isn't* built from C++? And *decompiling* a binary will not give an exact copy of the original source, far from it. And the problem isn't that we can't examine the blobs (reverse engineering binary files is an old and solved problem), it's that we can't *modify* them!

Comment: You are not helped by the source code [if the compiler is infected](http://wiki.c2.com/?TheKenThompsonHack).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But If you can reverse engineer it, you can write a new blob, which does what you want...

Comment: @BoPersson I am aware of the Ken Thompson hack, but I don't see what that has to do with this... I'm focusing on why we can't write our own binary blobs, by looking at the binary of the proprietary blobs...

Comment: Yes some of the blobs can be rewritten quite easily, and probably have been. But would you run a phone with such a piece of code? Get a single bit wrong and you might be breaking the law in most countries. Remember that many of the blobs are for things like the radio functionality etc., where there are strict regulations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude All we have to do is pick one phone, have a few thousand people crowd code it, have another few 1000 people test it, and we're set!

Answer (score 0):

A large number of people would find it very difficult to openly collaborate on an endeavour as you are suggesting because they would be afraid of legal intimidation and parasitic and restrictive IP-NDAs of various financially powerful entities.

As to your question about reverse engineering, there is an entire [stackexchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com) site dedicated to it. You could [get started](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31546/reversing-c-classes-in-arm) there.